# Microsoft Access - Look-up tables that only show records not previously matched

Tags: ms-access, limit, relationship, lookup

**Context:** I have three tables.

Table #1: Tbl_TraumaCodes: It marks all the dates, times, and hospital beds where a medical team is alerted to go treat a patient with a serious traumatic injury.

Table #2: Tbl_Location: Lists the date, time, and location (area of the hospital, bed number) where a patient was with an identifying number.

Table #3: Tbl_Outcomes: Has an identifying number paired with discharge outcomes.

**Task**: I need to with a reasonable amount of surety, match records in Tbl_TraumaCodes with Tbl_Outcomes.

Matching Tbl_Location and Tbl_Outcomes is easy and automatic through a matching query using the identifying number.  Matching Tbl_Location records with Tbl_Trauma Codes will create the link I need.

I designed a look-up table in Tbl_Location where the date, time, and location of records from Tbl_ TraumaCode appears so that I can match them.  However, the times that are supposed to correspond between Table_Location and Table_TraumaCode are not exactly the same. The times are roughly within the same ballpark (usually 30 +/- min).

**Problem**: I have thousands of records to match. There may only be 10 records on a given day, which allows me to limit the options when I type in, say, July 1st in the look-up table. Not every item in Tbl_Location with have a matching item in Tbl_TraumaCode. That means I have to match 10 records when there may be 40 extra record to work with. **It’s incorrect to assign an item (time) in Table_TraumaCode to more than one item in the Table_Location.** My goal is to reduce the potential for human error.

**Is there a way to make the records from the look-up table that are already assigned to a record within Tbl_Location NOT display in the look-up field?**  I thought about drawing the look-up table from a query, but I don’t know how I would create a TraumaCode query that only displays records that aren’t matched in another table. I also don't know if it would impact the previously assigned records.

I avail myself of the collective wisdom and humbly thank you.

Comment: Build a combobox RowSource that includes the lookup table and data table and apply filter on the lookup foreign key field in the data table: Is Null

Comment: Well, that would usually work but after reviewing your question again I see that your data structure will not allow for that. How would you expect to match records where the key data 'is not exactly the same'? Why is the location not an attribute in Tbl_TraumaCodes? If I correctly understand nature of this table data, it is to document specific trauma response events.

Comment: The location is an attribute in Tbl_TraumaCodes. It is not out of the ordinary to have certain locations to have an arrival and near immediate departure to the Operating Room, and then to be immediately populated again by another severe patient. Eliminating assigned tbl_TraumaCode records will make this task go from Herculean to merely daunting.

Comment: I am lost. Will have to provide sample data.

Comment: Not sure how to provide. Need to connect recs in Tbl_TraumaCodes to Tbl_PtOutcomes. Only way is to go through an intermediary: Tbl_Location. I can match records in Tbl_PtOutcomes and Tbl_Location by an ID code. Tbl_Location has a log of where a person was and when in a hospital. Tbl_TraumaCodes has date, time, location to alert a medical team to go treat a person now. I need to match the alert in Tbl_TraumaCodes to the log entry in Tbl_Location. There are extra Location entries with no match; person stays in hospital beyond the alert. Need to hide assigned alerts to not assign twice.

Comment: The times in the log and the alert never match perfectly because they are two different systems.

Comment: If you save ID of Tbl_Location record as foreign key in Tbl_TraumaCodes, then my suggestion in first comment should work. The query join needs to 'show all records from Tbl_Location...' so only location records not used will display in dropdown. If you are saving ID of Tbl_TraumaCodes into Tbl_Location then reverse the query. If you want to match records on date/time link, can't help you.

Comment: Followed the advice above. It worked yesterday on my test table, not today on my actual table, or testtable2. I had created a query of tbl_TraumaCodes with the ID of the Tbl_Location saved as a foreign key, with that field as Null. It removed already assigned items from my dropdown list (lookup field options) after the table refreshed. Today, I cant repeat. Same format for the query. Now when I try to assign the lookup field: "No valid fields can be found in the 'query.' You may have selected a query that uses the table you're adding to the lookup column to. Please choose another source."

Comment: SOLUTION: To avoid the message not to include the table you're adding to in the look-up column, make the query without that table first. Since I'm working in the Location table, I don't add the Location table in my query until the lookup table is established in the Location table. Then I can go back and edit my query to add in the Location foreign key with the Null criterian. After that, it works. You just have to work around the program protections. Hopefully this doesn't bite me later. Thank you June7!